# How to publish bytearray message with mosquitto_pub in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, mosquitto

I have a bash script which receive bytearray from python script and publish through mosquitto_pub but somehow bash is corrupting this data and on client side i am receiving wrong data.

**BashScript:**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -ne $(python Status.py) | mosquitto_pub -h localhost -t "component_status" -s
```

**Snippet of Python:**
Following are last line of python script

```
print( bytearray(myobj.SerializeToString()) )
sys.exit(0)
```

Same is working fine if I send this from python mqtt client, but I need to use shell for this purpose.

I also tried files option of mosquitto_pub like below but same result

```
echo -ne $(python Status.py) > status.bin
mosquitto_pub -h localhost -t "component_status" -f status.bin
```

It look like bash is not able to understand bytearray.

Comment: bash does not have data types; as far as it's concerned, everything is a string, and strings are not binary-safe (with the way you're using them, they're not even ASCII-safe). If you want bash to handle binary data, you pretty much need to encode it, as something like hex or base-64.

Comment: Why are you using echo? `python Status.py | mosquitto_pub ...`

Comment: @Shawn I tried this still same issue, to handle binary data we have to use echo with -ne.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks for hint, I changed to hex and then with xxd -r -p it work perfectly.

Comment: @ImranRazaKhan The pipe method should work; pipes *are* binary-safe (the shell creates them, but once created they're handled by the OS and the shell isn't involved in moving data through them). Is the python script printing a stray newline after the bytearray or something like that? Try `python Status.py | xxd` and make sure the output is exactly what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

After getting hint from @GordonDavisson, Following solution work for me

1. Change in Python - Convert bytearray to hex

   `print( binascii.hexlify( bytearray(myobj.SerializeToString()) ) )`
2. Change in bash - revert hex with xxd

   `python Status.py | xxd -r -p |mosquitto_pub -h localhost -t "component_status" -s`

Comment: Why use mosquitto_pub at all when there are perfectly good python MQTT client libraries like paho? https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/python/